# Making phonegap application that reads pages from web site

Tags: cordova

I would like to create a 'shell' phonegap application which displays content from another web site.  For example, I want to get content from our existing intranet and display it within a deployed phonegap application.  Is this possible?

(so when a user hits a link on the page, it just navigates within the shell to the next page).  I guess this would be like using phonegap as an iframe in a regular browser.

Is this possible? (reason: we have existing intranet and need to make accessible via phonegap application)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yes it's possible, just do an ajax call on the website and put the data into the html elements in your phone gap app.

Comment: Yes, I recognize that I can do ajax call to read in html, however, the links (urls) that the user clicks on would then redirect outside of the phonegap application.  This is not really what I am looking for.  I would like to host an entire site within a phonegap app.

Comment: Then change the links after you have done your ajax call, search for them and change them, or just use the text only after you retrieve back the data. Million and one ways to do this